# Numerical instability creating wrong result on Mixed-Integer Linear Program, bug or error?

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, or-tools

I created a bug ticket for Google or-tools Java library.
I was told it is a feature of Mixed-Integer solvers.

But those results for this simple program makes me think it is a bug, since I would have to round every coefficients in order to not get a wrong result.

Program:

```
Minimize epsPlus + epsMinus
x, y : integer
epsPlus, epsMinus : linear
19 <= x <= 23
21 <= y <= 47
x + y <= 60
x - 0.499999999y - epsPlus + epsMinus = 0
```

Results with different y coefficients on the last constraint:

```
0.499999990 working : objective=0.000000, x=20.000000, y=40.000000, epsPlus=0.000000, epsMinus=0.000000
0.499999999 failing : objective=1.500000, x=19.000000, y=41.000000, epsPlus=0.000000, epsMinus=1.500000
0.500000000 working : objective=0.000000, x=20.000000, y=40.000000, epsPlus=0.000000, epsMinus=0.000000
```

Can you confirm it is not a bug?

Minimal code:

```
Loader.loadNativeLibraries();
MPSolver solver = MPSolver.createSolver("SCIP");

// variables
MPVariable x = solver.makeIntVar(19, 23, "x");
MPVariable y = solver.makeIntVar(21, 47, "y");
MPVariable epsPlus = solver.makeNumVar(0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, "epsPlus");
MPVariable epsMinus = solver.makeNumVar(0, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, "epsMinus");

// constraints
MPConstraint constraint1 = solver.makeConstraint(60, 60, "constraint1");
constraint1.setCoefficient(x, 1);
constraint1.setCoefficient(y, 1);
MPConstraint constraint2 = solver.makeConstraint(0, 0, "constraint2");
constraint2.setCoefficient(x, 1);
constraint2.setCoefficient(y, -0.499999999);
constraint2.setCoefficient(epsPlus, -1);
constraint2.setCoefficient(epsMinus, 1);

// objective
MPObjective objective = solver.objective();
objective.setCoefficient(epsPlus, 1);
objective.setCoefficient(epsMinus, 1);
objective.setMinimization();

// result
solver.solve();
System.out.println(String.format("objective=%f, x=%f, y=%f, epsPlus=%f, epsMinus=%f", objective.value(), x.solutionValue(), y.solutionValue(), epsPlus.solutionValue(), epsMinus.solutionValue()));
```

https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/3098

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried with different solvers? Cbc?

Comment: @LaurentPerron Yes I just tested with CBC and it's working with any digit I want.
So it's a bug in SCIP. Can you reopen my ticket ?